# Windows CLI Integration in Adobe AIR 2.0 using NativeProcess for executable which opens own shell and blocks

Tags: actionscript-3, air, festival

How can I use the NativeProcess API in Adobe AIR 2.0 to do CLI in Windows like passing the following commands to cmd.exe

```
cd C:\FestivalTTS
echo "Hello world" | festival --tts
```

The problem is unlike grep or any unlike similar command, Festival opens its own shell and blocks cmd.exe prompt